# Handling badly behaved libraries that terminate process

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using LLVM right now. It has a disgusting habit of terminating the process on improper input, so that all the useful context and error messages and pretty much everything else of value is destroyed.

How can I intercept these process terminating calls so that I can perform some useful debugging? VS/Windows-specific answers are fine.

Comment: Do you need a solution that works when not attached to a debugger?

Comment: No, that's fine by me.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to suggest adding a breakpoint in std::terminate (or the disassembly), but I'm not sure if LLVM is actually calling std::terminate.

Comment: how terminating the process done ? , exit() ?

Comment: I believe it's using exit(). But in revision to my earlier comment, I'm actually running test cases involving generating LLVM code, and having the testing process be terminated when a test fails is the least useful behaviour ever. But I don't run the test process under a debugger most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do something with std::set_terminate, set_unexpected (only for unexpected  exception) and atexit ?

Comment: He is asking how to handle a terminating process. I suggest one way. Its an answer.

Comment: Answers should not really be phrased as questions, since they are answers, and not questions.

Comment: I can rephrase with "Have a look at ...", it won't change the content and it won't be a question...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up hooks for various things like `abort`, `signal`, unhandled exceptions and other unusual ways of exiting a program. If you provide your own handlers for there, you can just set a breakpoint in them to catch what's happening with a debugger attached, or save out minidumps/callstacks for when you're not attached.

There's lots of information on this kind of thing here:
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/07/22/more-adventures-in-failing-to-crash-properly/

Comment: Ah, though if it's calling `exit` as I just read in your comments, this is less useful! I wonder if `std::atexit` could help instead?